# Custom PHP form submission page in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, permalinks

I have a single page site with all content on it.  The only other page I have is a "thanks for submitting the contact form" page.  In this "thankssubmit.php" page I have my PHP form submission code.

I'm new to wordpress so I may be doing this totally wrong but I've created a custom page template for this "thankssubmit.php" page using `/*Template Name: Thanks Submit*/`.

I've then applied that template to a brand new page in WP.  I can't add .php to the slug which is maybe the only problem but I can't see a way around this.  A strange issue is that when I submit the form I go to the correct URL but get a "page not found" error.  If I copy and paste this exact same URL I go to the correct page...

Below is the code for all.

I've had a look and I can't see this question being a repeat but if so a nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Form

```
<form method="post" action="thankssubmit.php">
        <h3>Drop Us a Message</h3>
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input id="nameInput" type="text" name="name" onkeyup="manage(this)" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input id="emailInput" type="text" name="email" onkeyup="manage(this)" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone Number" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input id="weddingDatePicker" type="date" name="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Wedding Date -" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="hear" class="form-control" placeholder="How did you hear about us?" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea id="messageInput" name="message" onkeyup="manage(this)" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message *" style="width: 100%; height: 254px;"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <input id="contactSubmitBtn" type="submit" disabled name="btnSubmit" class="btn" value="Send Message" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

thankssubmit.php page

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<!-- THANKS OR SUCCESS MESSAGE AFTER THE EMAIL HAS BEEN SENT -->
<section id="thanksMsgPG">

<h1 class="thanksmsg">Thanks for getting in touch.</h1>
<h3 class="thanksmsg">We'll get back to you ASAP!</h3>
<a href="/"><button class="btn ">Back</button></a>

</section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>


<?php

/*
Template Name: Thanks Submit
*/


if (isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])) {

    // EMAIL AND SUBJECT OF EMAIL BEING SENT
    $email_to = "hello@everafterfilmsni.com";
    $subject = "Contact Submission Form";

//ERROR MESSAGES IF DIED FUCNTION IS CALLED (SEMI-REDUNDANT BECAUSE SEND BUTTON WONT BE ENABLED UNTIL INPUT FIELDS ARE FILLED CORRECTLY ANYWAY)
    function died($error)
    {

        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error . "<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // IF NOTHING ENTERED THEN THROW ERROR MESSAGE
    if (!isset($_POST['name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['message'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
    }

//GETTING THE NAME EMAIL PHONE MESSAGE FROM THE FORM AND PUTTING IT INTO VARIABLES
    $full_name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $hear = $_POST['hear']; // required
    $message = $_POST['message']; // required


    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

//CHECKING TO MAKE SURE VALID EMAIL IS ENTERED
    if (!preg_match($email_exp, $email_from)) {
        $error_message .= 'The e-mail you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
//CHECKING TO MAKE SURE VALID NAME IS ENTERED
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
    if (!preg_match($string_exp, $full_name)) {
        $error_message .= 'The name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
//CHECKING TO MAKE SURE MESSAGE IS MORE THAN 2 CHARACTERS
    if (strlen($message) < 2) {
        $error_message .= 'The message you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    if (strlen($error_message) > 0) {
        died($error_message);
    }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

//MAKING SURE THERE ARE NO HEADER INJECTIONS
    function clean_string($string)
    {
        $bad = array("content-type", "bcc:", "to:", "cc:", "href");
        return str_replace($bad, "", $string);
    }

//THE FORMAT OF THE EMAIL BEING SENT. CLEAN STRING CLEANING ANY WHITE SPACE
    $email_message .= "Name: " . clean_string($full_name) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: " . clean_string($email_from) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Phone: " . clean_string($phone) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Wedding Date: " . clean_string($date) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "I heard about you via: " . clean_string($hear) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Message: \r\n" . clean_string($message) . "\n";
    $email_from = $full_name . '<' . $email_from . '>';

// CREATING EMAIL HEADER FOR GMAIL TO RECOGNISE
    $headers = 'From: ' . $email_from . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: ' . $email_from . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    @mail($email_to, $subject, $email_message, $headers);

    // echo $email_message;

    ?>

<?php
}
?>
```

I'VE ADDED TWO IMAGES - First image below shows the URL error after we submit the form and the second shows after we reload the pages URL.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

/*  for this issue to make it resolve you suppose to use below any one method  */
method 1) action value=get_permalink($page->ID)
method 2) action value= site_url().'/thankssubmit' // or whatever URL as per your permalink structure

/* try if it is working or not */

Comment: Permalink in the action section of the form won't work because the action has to point to the page that holds the PHP form. :(